# Sub query with MAXDATE error Msg 208, Invalid object name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm not a SQL expert, would you know why my inner joins to sub query do not list most recent MAXDATE? Simply just seeking to have my query do is return MAXDATE from (Monthly_Charge_Date), I tried the following and I keep getting error

Msg 208
Invalid object name

Really what I would like see is the most recent MAXDATE with residents table. My data is not completed unless I am able to see the sub query throughput from res.Accept_Checks, Active Property.

```
SELECT  
    res.Accept_Checks, 
    (SELECT MAX(bld.Monthly_Charge_Date) maxDate
     FROM      
         (SELECT DISTINCT,
              bld.Monthly_Charge_Date,
              bld.Building_Name,
              unt.Unit_Number,
              res.Accept_Checks, 
              unt.Occupied_Status,
              enti.Active,
              enti.Entity_Number
          FROM   
              dbo.units AS unt
          INNER JOIN 
              dbo.residents AS res ON unt.Unit_ID = res.Unit_ID 
          INNER JOIN 
              dbo.buildings AS bld ON unt.Building_ID = bld.Building_ID 
          INNER JOIN 
              dbo.gl_entities AS enti ON bld.GL_Entity_ID = enti.GL_Entity_ID 
          INNER JOIN 
              dbo.resident_credit_history AS rsch ON res.Resident_ID = rsch.Resident_ID 
          INNER JOIN 
              dbo.credit_codes AS crhc ON rsch.History_Code_ID = crhc.History_Code_ID
          WHERE 
              bld.Monthly_Charge_Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())
              AND enti.active = 1
              AND crhc.active = 1 
              AND bld.building_Active = 1 
              AND unt.Occupied_Status = 1
              AND CHECKS = 0) res) MaxDate,
    res.Accept_Checks
FROM    
    dbo.residents
ORDER BY 
    bld.Monthly_Charge_Date DESC, bld.Building_Name
```

Comment: Simplify, [mcve].

Comment: Whats the full error msg? SQL Server normally tells you the column name.

Comment: @Dale K, Full Error Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.residents'. Checks comes from table: dbo.residents AS res

Comment: @hmm4089 that means your table, residents, doesn't exist... are you sure you are running against the correct database?

Comment: @Dale K, yes table exists with correct database.

Comment: Does `select count(*) from dbo.Residents` work? If so, start fixing the other errors I listed above.

Answer (score -1):

You need `MAX(res.Monthly_Charge_Date) maxDate` in your second select statement.

Comment: That doesn't even begin to address the multiple issues in this query.

Comment: @vtuhtan, your response is not correct for my query.